# Aligning 2 buttons to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons nested inside a Horizontal LinearLayout, and I want to align them both to the bottom of the screen. I've set the LinearLayout's `weightsum` property to 1 & the 2 buttons' `layoutweight` property also to 1 & I get this result :

[image]

I get this weird space around the buttons and I want to eliminate it. How to ?

Here is the XML code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hourlyDailyLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hourlyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hourly"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dailyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/daily"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is that your complete xml or is it inside of a `RelativeLayout` or anything else? Also, I would steer away from having them completely at the bottom if at all possible with the hardware buttons down there.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but I don't appreciate the downvote... just the fact that you are an old member does not give you the right to crush other people who are trying to learn. The question is clear, well argumented. Answer the question or take a walk.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but way to jump to conclusions about me. That won't make it easier to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons have padding by default. They way to combat that is to set negative margins

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/dailyButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/daily"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
    />
```

Comment: it is a work around yes... still waiting for something more.. straightforward. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DeveloperX would button without background be ok? Its like flat button just text

Comment: yep, I used your negative margin technique, couldn't find another way.

Answer (score -2):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/hourlyButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/hourly"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dailyButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/daily"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    />
```

set the width to 0dp

Comment: change the padding and margin to 0 for both buttons